# How to use more than one custom javascript css carousel on same page?

Tags: javascript

I am using an image carousel which is working perfectly. Except that I can't use 2nd, 3rd carousel on same page. If I use more than one carousel on same page than the 2nd and 3rd are not working only the 1st. I am not expert and need some help if it possbile to change the code and have more than one carousel on same page? Here is the code:

Style:

```
/** img-carousel **/
#imgages-carousel {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    padding: 40px 0px;
}
.img-carousel-container {
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
}
.img-carousel {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth; 
    padding-bottom: 5px; 
}
.img-carousel div {
    flex: none;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
}
.img-carousel div img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.img-carousel div p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.img-carousel-container button {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 15px);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.7);
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
#prev {
    left: 10px;
}
#next {
    right: 10px;
}
.img-carousel-container:hover button {
    opacity: 1;
}
.img-carousel-container button:hover {
    background-color: #ffc107;
}

/** custom scrollbar **/
.img-carousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
.img-carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ffc107;
    border-radius: 10px;
   
}
.img-carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
.img-carousel-container:hover .img-carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    visibility: visible;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .img-carousel-container {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .img-carousel div  {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Script:

```
const carousel = document.querySelector('.img-carousel');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev');
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');
let carsouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.img-carousel div');

//Next Carousel
const nextCarousel = () => {
    if(carsouselImages[carsouselImages.length - 1]) {
      carousel.scrollTo(0, 0); 
    } 
      carousel.scrollBy(300, 0);
};

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  nextCarousel(); 
});

//Prev Carousel
const prevCarousel = () => {
   if(carsouselImages[0]) {
    carousel.scrollTo(4800,0);
   }
    carousel.scrollBy(-300, 0); 
};

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
   prevCarousel(); 
});


// Auto carousel
const auto = true; // Auto scroll
const intervalTime = 5000;
let sliderInterval;


if (auto) {
  sliderInterval = setInterval(nextCarousel, intervalTime);
};

carousel.addEventListener('mouseover', (stopInterval) => {
  clearInterval(sliderInterval);
});

carousel.addEventListener('mouseleave', (startInterval) => {
  if (auto) {
    sliderInterval = setInterval(nextCarousel, intervalTime);
  }
}); 

//for mobile events
carousel.addEventListener('touchstart', (stopIntervalT) => {
    clearInterval(sliderInterval);
});
carousel.addEventListener('touchend', (startIntervalT) => {
   if (auto) {
    sliderInterval = setInterval(nextCarousel, intervalTime);
  }
});

//Debounce
var previousCall;
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    if (previousCall >= 0) {
        clearTimeout(previousCall);
    } 
    previousCall = setTimeout(() => {
      carousel.scrollBy(-300, 0); 
    }, 200);
});
```

Html:

```
   <!-- section images carousel -->
       <section id="imgages-carousel">
            <div class="img-carousel-container">
                   <div class="img-carousel">
                       <div>
                       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/9Nok_iZEgLk/800x450">
                           <p>1/6</p>
                       </div>
                       <div>
                       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/4v7ubW7jz1Q/800x450"> 
                           <p>2/6</p>
                       </div>
                       <div>
                       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/rtCujH697DU/800x450"> 
                           <p>3/6</p>
                       </div>
                       <div>
                       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ELv8fvulR0g/800x450"> 
                           <p>4/6</p>
                       </div>
                       <div>
                       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/LoPGu6By90k/800x450"> 
                           <p>5/6</p>
                       </div>
                       <div>
                       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Ndz3w6MCeWc/800x450">
                           <p>6/6</p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <button id="prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></button>
                   <button id="next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></button> 
               </div>        
       </section>
```

Comment: Are you running the appropriate javascript code in relation to the selectors of the new Carousel? In another words for a new carousel you need to run the same code as for  your first one but using the right selectors of the new carousel.

Comment: I try changing the selectors for second carousel adding '2' at the end but there too many selectors and I can't make it work right. Any help with that ?

Comment: Other option is to select all of the carousels and loop through them adding the functionality, you also need to loop through the buttons to add appropriate listeners to to appropriate buttons. Otherwise you would be controlling all carousels with every button.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean but as I'm not an expert, its not possible for me to do it.

Comment: Check my solution. Do you understand what I mean with the styles?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Keep in mind that IDs must be unique per page, so you cannot use something like `<button id="prev">` multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution looping through the carousels. All you need to do is to make sure your styles are added. There are styles based on the id of the carousels - that needs to be added for all of them or made universal.

Here is little bit revised answer, no need to declare the functions and variables several times inside the forLoop like it was before.

What this code does it selects all carousels with the class .img-carousel and loops through them. Adding functionality to each carousel and relative buttons (based on index). The core functionality is the same only now it is added dynamically.

```js
const carousels = document.querySelectorAll('.img-carousel');
const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.prev');
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.next');
let carsouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.img-carousel div');

//Next Carousel
const nextCarousel = (carousel) => {
    if(carsouselImages[carsouselImages.length - 1]) {
      carousel.scrollTo(0, 0); 
    } 
      carousel.scrollBy(300, 0);
};
//Prev Carousel
const prevCarousel = (carousel) => {
   if(carsouselImages[0]) {
    carousel.scrollTo(4800,0);
   }
    carousel.scrollBy(-300, 0); 
};

// Auto carousel


carousels.forEach((carousel, index)=>{
nextBtn[index].addEventListener('click', e => {
  nextCarousel(carousel); 
});
prevBtn[index].addEventListener('click', e => {
   prevCarousel(carousel); 
});
// Auto carousel
const auto = true; // Auto scroll
const intervalTime = 5000;
let sliderInterval;
let previousCall;

if (auto) {
  sliderInterval = setInterval(()=>nextCarousel(carousel), intervalTime);
};

carousel.addEventListener('mouseover', (stopInterval) => {
  clearInterval(sliderInterval);
});

carousel.addEventListener('mouseleave', (startInterval) => {
  if (auto) {
    sliderInterval = setInterval(()=>nextCarousel(carousel), intervalTime);
  }
}); 

//for mobile events
carousel.addEventListener('touchstart', (stopIntervalT) => {
    clearInterval(sliderInterval);
});
carousel.addEventListener('touchend', (startIntervalT) => {
   if (auto) {
    sliderInterval = setInterval(()=>nextCarousel(carousel), intervalTime);
  }
});

//Debounce
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    if (previousCall >= 0) {
        clearTimeout(previousCall);
    } 
    previousCall = setTimeout(() => {
      carousel.scrollBy(-300, 0); 
    }, 200);
}); 
});
```

```css
/** img-carousel **/
#imgages-carousel {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    padding: 40px 0px;
}
#imgages-carousel1 {
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    padding: 40px 0px;
}
.img-carousel-container {
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
}
.img-carousel {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth; 
    padding-bottom: 5px; 
}
.img-carousel div {
    flex: none;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
}
.img-carousel div img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.img-carousel div p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.img-carousel-container button {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 15px);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 193, 7, 0.7);
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.prev {
    left: 10px;
}
.next {
    right: 10px;
}
.img-carousel-container:hover button {
    opacity: 1;
}
.img-carousel-container button:hover {
    background-color: #ffc107;
}

/** custom scrollbar **/
.img-carousel::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
.img-carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ffc107;
    border-radius: 10px;
   
}
.img-carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
.img-carousel-container:hover .img-carousel::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    visibility: visible;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .img-carousel-container {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .img-carousel div  {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- section images carousel -->
<section id="imgages-carousel">
  <div class="img-carousel-container">
    <div class="img-carousel">
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/9Nok_iZEgLk/800x450">
        <p>1/6</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/4v7ubW7jz1Q/800x450">
        <p>2/6</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/rtCujH697DU/800x450">
        <p>3/6</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ELv8fvulR0g/800x450">
        <p>4/6</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/LoPGu6By90k/800x450">
        <p>5/6</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Ndz3w6MCeWc/800x450">
        <p>6/6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i></button>
    <button class="next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></button>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="imgages-carousel1">
  <div class="img-carousel-container">
    <div class="img-carousel">
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/9Nok_iZEgLk/800x450">
        <p>1/6</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/4v7ubW7jz1Q/800x450">
        <p>2/6</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/rtCujH697DU/800x450">
        <p>3/6</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/ELv8fvulR0g/800x450">
        <p>4/6</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/LoPGu6By90k/800x450">
        <p>5/6</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Ndz3w6MCeWc/800x450">
        <p>6/6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="prev"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-2x "></i></button>
    <button class="next"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-2x "></i></button>
  </div>
  
</section>
```

Comment: It is almost working right. Except that the autoplay is not working now

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: My bad, didn't copy that part of the code. Alternatively you can manually add the listeners for each carousel to ensure sync or custom timing for each carousel.

Comment: Don't worry about that. Also check the latest edit with little better practices.

Comment: Sir I know its been long time since you answer but why didn't carousel loop to the first image when it reach the last image of carousel. its just freeze on the last..